# pointing site to Route 53 for a domain already pointing to Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, cloudflare

Here's the situation we are facing.

We have our client who has pointed their domain to cloudflare DNS [
    we've set that domain already in our cloudflare account ].
Now the
    site is to be hosted via AWS S3 I've configured my bucket to run
    through route 53, but when I try to create A record entry in
    cloudflare pointing to route53 dns which looks like this :
    `ns-212.awsdns-26.com` but A record would always need an IP4 address.
    How do i go around it ?

How should I configure entry in cloudflare so it points correctly to my Route53 which in turn will point to S3 bucket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a CNAME to your S3 bucket rather than an A record. 
You can't have two providers running your DNS although you can delegate a subdomain to another provider if that is what you want to do.

Comment: great thanks. I pointed S3 bucket URL to as CNAME in cloudlfare and it worked.